# Using vsce via command line in Github Action throws Invalid publisher name error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-extensions

We have an existing extension that is already in the VS Code market place.
I'm trying to automate publishing by using Github Actions and executing this command...

`vsce publish -p ${{ secrets.VSCODE_PAT }}`

When the command executes I'm getting this error:

> ERROR  Invalid publisher name 'Wilderness Labs'. Expected the
> identifier of a publisher, not its human-friendly name.

The vscode documentation doesn't really help in this situation. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: "The vscode documentation doesn't really help in this situation"? Did you even read this, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/continuous-integration#automated-publishing?

Comment: @LexLi I did not see that, so didn't see the section about...
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "vsce publish --yarn"
}

Comment: @LexLi Switching to to what they say in the docs, gives exactly the same error.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/extension-anatomy#extension-manifest instead of `Wilderness Labs`, `vsce` looks for things like `wilderness-labs` in your `package.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've narrowed it down now.

Answer (score 0):

The publisher name MUST NOT be a string literal with spaces. As mentioned by @Lex it needs to be a something like WildernessLabs or wilderness-labs or whatever it is for your own organisation.